# My discord bot's pi command isn't working

Tags: file, import, discord, discord.py

I made a discord bot with a lot of commands. The whole thing was in main.py, which made it very difficult to find one of the entire list of commands when I wanted to make some changes. So, I decided to make each command into a new file, and then import the file back into main.py. (So for example, before the code was `@bot.command() async def pi(ctx, digits):`, but now the `@bot.command() async def pi(ctx, digits):` has been put into a file called `pi.py`) I just use the pi command as an example.

Here is my code in main.py:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

import asyncio

from pi.py import Pi

token = "hidden for saftey lol"

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?", intents=intents)
bot.add_cog(Pi(bot))

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=f"?help"))
  await asyncio.sleep(1)
  print("\n Bot has successfully logged in as: {}".format(bot.user))
  print("Bot ID: {}\n".format(bot.user.id))


try:
  bot.run(token)
except discord.HTTPException as e:
  if e.status == 429:
    print("The Discord servers denied the connection for making too many requests")
  else:
    raise e
```

and here is my code in pi.py:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import decimal

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?", intents=intents)

class Pi(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, bot):
    self.bot = bot
  @bot.command()
  async def pi(ctx, num_decimals: int):
    if num_decimals > 10000:
      await ctx.send("Sorry, I can only print up to 10000 decimal places.")
      return
    decimal.getcontext().prec = num_decimals + 1
    pi_value = decimal.Decimal(0)
    for i in range(num_decimals + 1):
      pi_value += (decimal.Decimal(1) / 16 ** i) * ((decimal.Decimal(4) / (8 * i + 1)) - (decimal.Decimal(2) / (8 * i + 4)) - (decimal.Decimal(1) / (8 * i + 5)) - (decimal.Decimal(1) / (8 * i + 6)))
    pi_str = str(pi_value)[:num_decimals + 1]
    await ctx.send(f"The value of pi to {num_decimals} decimal places is: {pi_str}")

def setup(bot):
  bot.add_cog(Pi(bot))
```

Just a reminder since I forgot to say at the beginning, the pi.py is inside a folder called "cogs". I've shown a photo of how it looks.
The problem I have is importing the file. When I run the code, it gives me this error: `Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 9, in <module> from pi.py import Pi ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pi'`

Please help. I would be very thankful for the answer.

Comment: If the file is called `pi.py`, then you want `from pi import Pi`. This only works if your directory `cogs` is in the Python path.

Comment: Oh, nvm, I asked chatgpt and it told me to change `from pi.py import Pi` to `from cogs.pi import Pi` and it worked. Also, I tried `from pi import Pi` and that didn't work too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main is a little messy so I'll show you 2 ways you can make your main. Doing it my way and your way.

My way:
This way, the cogs will be auto-loaded into your main function and should work right off the bat without ever needing to change the main file again.

```
import discord                                                                                                                                
from discord.ext import commands                                                                                                              
import os
import traceback

def get_cogs():
    cogs_dir = "./cogs"  # Directory path

    # Get all file names in directory and filter out non-Python files
    file_names = [f[:-3] for f in os.listdir(cogs_dir) if f.endswith(".py")]

    # Add "cogs." to the beginning of file_name
    cogs = ["cogs." + filename for filename in file_names]

    print(f"\n\nTHE FILES IN THE COG FOLDER ARE: {cogs}\n\n")
    return cogs


class Bot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or('.'), intents=discord.Intents().all())
        self.cogsList = get_cogs()

    async def setup_hook(self):
        for ext in self.cogsList:
            await self.load_extension(ext)
    
    async def on_ready(self): 
        await self.change_presence(activity=discord.Game('the game your bot is playing'))

        # Replace the channel ID with the actual ID you want to send the message to
        channel = self.get_channel(1072747266747670541)
        await channel.send('7.5 million years have passed...\nThe answer is ready:\nThe Ultimate Answer to Life, The Universe, and Everything is...42!')
        
        print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(self))
        try:
            synced = await self.tree.sync()
            print(f'Synced {len(synced)} command(s)')
        except Exception as e:
            tb = e.__traceback__
            lineno = tb.tb_lineno
            traceback.print_exc()
            print(f"An Error Occurred in loading the commands on line {lineno}:\n{e}")


bot = Bot()


bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Main #2:
(your code rewritten)
Instead of importing from pi.py, you should import from the actual file name without the extension. it should be `from pi import Pi`

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

import asyncio

from pi import Pi

token = "hidden for safety lol"

intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?", intents=intents)
bot.add_cog(Pi(bot))

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="?help"))
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("\nBot has successfully logged in as: {}".format(bot.user))
    print("Bot ID: {}\n".format(bot.user.id))


try:
    bot.run(token)
except discord.HTTPException as e:
    if e.status == 429:
        print("The Discord servers denied the connection for making too many requests")
    else:
        raise e
```

You had a couple of things wrong here.

1. you shouldn't use `bot.command()` inside of a cog. For prefix commands you should be using `@commands.command()`
2. you had a couple of mistakes in the reference back to the main at the very end of your cog. your def needs to be `async` and your `bot.add_cog()` function needs to have an `await` at the beginning as well as having the parameters `(bot:commands.Bot)`
3. In the pi command within the Pi cog, the ctx parameter is missing the self argument. because this is a class you need to have it referenced.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import decimal

class Pi(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
  
    @commands.command()
    async def pi(self, ctx, num_decimals: int):
        if num_decimals > 10000:
            await ctx.send("Sorry, I can only print up to 10000 decimal places.")
            return
        decimal.getcontext().prec = num_decimals + 1
        pi_value = decimal.Decimal(0)
        for i in range(num_decimals + 1):
            pi_value += (decimal.Decimal(1) / 16 ** i) * ((decimal.Decimal(4) / (8 * i + 1)) - (decimal.Decimal(2) / (8 * i + 4)) - (decimal.Decimal(1) / (8 * i + 5)) - (decimal.Decimal(1) / (8 * i + 6)))
        pi_str = str(pi_value)[:num_decimals + 1]
        await ctx.send(f"The value of pi to {num_decimals} decimal places is: {pi_str}")

async def setup(bot:commands.Bot) -> None:
    await bot.add_cog(Pi(bot))
```